# How to use a variable inside a Power Automate expression

Tags: flow

I'm trying to work with the **setProperty** function in order to edit a JSON body during the execution of a flow, here is the expression:

```
setProperty(X, 'Y','bla bla 123456789' )
```

while

- X is the json
- Y the property i want to modify
- 'bla bla 123456789' is the value

My question is: how can I replace '123456789' by a variable('ID') inside it, if I do the following thing

```
setProperty(X, 'Y','bla bla variable('ID')' )
```

It will take exactly what is written "variable('ID') and not the value of this variable !

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your variables('ID') within a string declaration so the variables object is not being accessed. You must concatenate the two separate strings ('bla bla' and variables('ID')); to do so, use the concat() function.

Your expression would look like this:

```
setProperty(X, 'Y', concat('bla bla ', variables('ID')))
```

---

If I am understanding the case you presented in the comments correctly, I believe you can still use the concat() function to accomplish this.
You would need to concatenate the whole 'path' value with your variable ID.

The path value:

```
'/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''.../sites/Support''))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''def533d7-8ede-4f29-b882-57d48a90c2d8''))}/onupdateditems'
```

would then become:

```
concat('/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''.../sites/Support''))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''', variables('ID'), '''))}/onupdateditems')
```

Note that I am retaining the extra quotation marks to preserve the syntax of the original value.

The whole expression then becomes:

```
setProperty(body('Get_Flow')['properties']['definition'],'triggers', setProperty(body('Get_Flow')['properties']['definition']['triggers'], 'When_an_item_is_created_or_modified',setProperty(body('Get_Flow')['properties']['definition']['triggers']['When_an_item_is_created_or_modified'], 'inputs',setProperty(body('Get_Flow')['properties']['definition']['triggers']['When_an_item_is_created_or_modified']['inputs'], 'path',concat('/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''.../sites/Support''))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(''', variables('ID'), '''))}/onupdateditems')))))
```

Comment: I understand your proposition ! what about this difficult case:

Comment: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Duplicate-an-existing-flow-inside-another-Automated-flow/td-p/440607

Comment: and let me ask you, when i use concat() function you agree with me that the result is a string, how can i execute that customised funcion setProperty()?

Comment: @AIMENBOULAHIA Please see my modified answer.

Comment: Indeed, I already used this, thank you jRDF1